# spring data mongo upsert on embedded array of objects and main document

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, spring-data-mongodb

My collection is as below;

```
{
   "_id" : "1",
    "firstName" : "paul",
    "dob" : "2012-12-12",
    "friends" [ {
                  "_id" : "friend_1",
                  "firstName" : "Karan"
                },
                {
                  "_id" : "friend_2",
                  "firstName" : "Chasay"
                } 
              ]
}
```

Now I want to perform `upsert` on both nested, and main document
Input Json as below

```
{  
   "_id" : "1", 
   "lastName" : "Cary", 
    "firstName" : "paul",
    "dob" : "2012-12-12", 
   "friends" : [ 
                 {
                   "_id" : "friend_1",
                   "lastName" : "Eric"
                  },
                 {
                   "_id" : "friend_3",
                   "lastName" : "Charan"
                  }  
                  ] 
   }
```

Output should be

```
{  
   "_id" : "1", 
   "lastName" : "Cary", 
   "friends" : [ 
                 {
                   "_id" : "friend_1",
                   "lastName" : "Eric",
                   "firstName" : "Karan"
                  },
                 {
                   "_id" : "friend_3",
                   "lastName" : "Charan"
                  } ,
                 {
                  "_id" : "friend_2",
                  "firstName" : "Chasay"
                }  
                  ] 
   }
```

The thing is this should be done in one query, if not possible please suggest,

What I have tried:

```
Query q  =new Query().addCriteria(Cirtiera.where("_id").is(person.getId()));
Document doc = new Document();
template.getConverter().write(person, doc);
Update update = Update.fromDocument("$set", doc);
template.upsert(q, update, Person.class);
```

The above query upserts the main object, but replaces whole `friends` list,
I want to use `Criteria.where("_id").is(person.getId()).and("friends.id").is(person.getFriendsList().getId())`
this query to make upsert in embedded array.

how can I achieve that ?

Comment: I think you just want to _push_ data into an array of embedded documents in an update operation (I dont think that is referred as _upsert_). You can use operators like `$push` and `$set`: [Update Operators](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/).

Comment: @prasad_  not just `$push` or `$set` I need to do all at once, if item in array not found, it should `push` if field in item object of an array is not found then `$set` all this should happen in a single query.